# Best automated testing approaches to test a WPF MVVM User Interface

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-interface, automated-tests

I would like to know the best automated testing approaches to test a C# WPF MVVM XBAP application. I know there is something called "Coded UI Test" approach in visual studio. 
My queries:
1.Is it advisable to use "Coded UI" or is there any other better open source testing tool other than visual studio's Coded UI? 
2.What are the differences, i mean feature wise between VS2010 and VS2012 "Coded UI Test" ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you need UI tests? In my experience, you're in for a world of pain and will wind up with brittle tests that are more trouble than they're worth. Maybe look into testing your VMs extensively instead? I've found that approach to be a very reasonable trade-off, especially with RxUI.

Comment: Hi Kent, Thanks for ur suggestion. No other testing tool best support a WPF XBAP application except Coded UI. I have started working on it, but I encounter difficulties in recognising the controls present inside a WPF TabControl. Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: This is the world of pain to which I refer. It may be that the controls are in an deselected tab. The `TabControl` loads only the selected tab, and unloads it when the user selects another tab. That may be the issue, but I'm really just guessing without seeing specifics.

Comment: Its liike even the controls in a selected tab are not identified, seeme like i have to write extensions and manually drill down the UI tree.